# In Principle, is it possible to set a recording to stop automatically on the last frame of an animation?

Tags: principle-app

I have a simple animation that I'd like to create a gif for. I want to record the full animation from 0 -> 100% only once and stop automatically at the last frame (100%). Currently I try to click the stop recording button on the last frame, but this is tricky to do of course.

Is there a way to record the set animation and for it to automatically stop recording at the last frame?

Comment: Something is missing. your trying to convert a  video to a gif with screncapture or...? Turn each frame toa image and read all images.

Comment: The gif is created by Principle, and it all works fine, but when you set up the animations to be infinite (you hook them up to go in a circle), when you try to record the animation to then save the gif, the recording system replays the animation over and over, and it creates a gif of it all, so it's hard to save a perfect frame #1 -> last frame gif. I end up with a gif that doesn't replay infinitely because the last frame in it isn't the last frame. I'm currently trying to stop the recording at the last frame manually, which is hard/not ideal.

Comment: Ok, Quick tip. Due to the way human memory works. You shouldn't rely on Tags and Headers to hold your critical data. You should always include the same info in the introduction of your body text. Because the 3 slots are in different memory containers (especially on stack exchange since they really are in a different box). This is the same kind of thing as you forgetting what you were after once you left the room. This kind of redundancy will make you a much better writer. Anyway, wouldn't it be easier just to repackage the gif outside your app?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's possible, but you can use the shortcut `Ctrl + V` instead of having to click the stop recording button which could minimise error.

Additionally you could try adding in a "mark" (e.g. full red screen) for the last frame for a specific time limit, and then edit the gif so that it cuts out this last frame.